# docker compose access service using bridge IP and custom port

Tags: docker

I have the below service in docker compose:

```yaml
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    networks:
      my_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.22.0.11
    ports:
      - 3307:3306

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.22.0.0/27
```

When I bring this up, I am able to access the db using `localhost:3307`. When I remove the `ports` section, I can access the db using `172.22.0.11:3306`.

I though that by having both the configurations, the DB should be accessible using `172.22.0.11:3307`. Is this not the case? Also, it is possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The db container exposes port 3306 on whatever network it is attached to. In this case, my_network.

The `ports:` directive tells docker to expose the port on the *external* network and how to map it to the local port. In this case, port 3307 is exposed on your localhost and maps to port 3306 on my_network.